# Protractor - How to create new browser/driver with different capabilities?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I would like to use proxy settings for a subset of my specs. I am aware of the forkNewDriverInstance as described [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md). But, after a having a look at the [code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/667111856627b9e81bedb92f3337fb0aba5a139c/lib/runner.js#L209), I fear it is not possible to alter the capabilities passed on the configuration file.

Considering my intent, to have proxy settings only for some of my specs. Is there a proper approach to this? Is there any setting I am not aware?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why would you like different proxy settings for some of the tests?

Comment: @MichalCharemza Maybe I need to be more specific. Certain functionality is related to the users country. I would like to use different proxies to test the functionality for these locations.

Comment: And then does the proxy simulate requests from different countries in some way, or are the proxies actually located there?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to simulate requests coming from those locations. @MichalCharemza

Comment: In what way specifically?

Comment: My idea is that by setting a proxy address (pick one from the internet probably) from a given country I'd like to test, the site will react as if an actual user would be on such location. @MichalCharemza

Comment: Ah, so the server will see requests coming from an IP that is located in the country you're testing for? (My reason for these questions is to determine exactly what solution will help you: how a proxy/proxies can be setup to get what you need)

Comment: No worries, coming to think about it I don't think my question actually makes this clear. I'll update it so it reflects my final intent.